# Accessing package.json from another packge

Tags: node.js, package.json

In NodeJS, can a package A access the `package.json` file of another package B?

Imagine, package A publishes a module. The behavior I want, is that this published module can access the `package.json` file of package B when it is imported into a module of package B. However, when the same module is imported into another package C, it needs to access the `package.json` of package C. This still needs to work, even if the modules of the packages B and C are imported into yet another package.

Bottom line is: Is it possible to have a module access the `package.json` of a package that it was imported into?

If possible, I want a solution that does not rely on something like an `init()` function that simply takes the path to the package.json file as a parameter.

So far I am only aware that a package can access its *own* `package.json`. This is done by simply importing/requireing the `package.json` file, but I do not belive this approach does help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `node_modules` in any case.
Note that this won't work if the module is not installed.

Here an example:

```js
const path = require('path')
const moduleMain = require.resolve('commander') // an installed module
const pathDetails = path.parse(moduleMain)
const packagePath = path.join(pathDetails.dir, 'package.json')
console.log(require(packagePath))
```